# no slashes needed in date string provided via zenity

Tags: text-processing, zenity

By using the `zenity` utility, select the date from the calendar; the output is `19/09/2022`. I want to remove slashes between the parts of the date to make it `19092022` and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `zenity`](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/calendar.html.sl) (or `man zenity`) this is handled directly (the example even shows how to do this directly):

> **`--date-format=format`** Specifies the format that is returned from the calendar dialog after date selection. The default format depends on your locale. Format must be a format that is acceptable to the strftime function, for example `%A %d/%m/%y`.

In your case,

```
--date-format='%d/%m/%y'
```

So

```
zenity --calendar \
    --title="Select a Date" \
    --text="Click on a date to select that date." \
    --date-format='%d/%m/%y'
```